# Improvement over John Resig's JavaScript class framework

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

Good day all,

I've recently been looking around for a nice simple JavaScript class framework which only does basic inheritance. I found [John Resig's example framework](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/) on his blog and I find it to be quite satisfactory for my needs. However, the post dates from 2008, and this is, after all, the web we're talking about.

So my question is, would you guys use that system as is, or would there be improvements to make, things that have been discovered over the years? Or perhaps an existing, actively supported class framework that resembles this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The guys of [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com) did a great job of creating a [Class implementation](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=jQuery.Class) based on John Resigs framework example:

> Class provides simulated inheritance
>   in JavaScript. Use clss to bridge the
>   gap between jQuery's functional
>   programming style and Object Oriented
>   Programming. It is based off John
>   Resig's Simple Class Inheritance
>   library. Besides prototypal
>   inheritance, it includes a few
>   important features:
>
> ```
> Static inheritance
> Introspection
> Namespaces
> Setup and initialization methods
> Easy callback function creation
> ```

All other parts of the framework are based on Class but you can also use it standalone (less than 6Kb compressed). I especially like the callback functions and the static inheritance. Use it like this:

```
$.Class.extend('My.Class',
{
    // Static properties
},
{
    init : function(args)
    {
            // This is the constructor
    },

    classMethod : function()
    {
        alert("Class method called.");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you point me to where the definition can be found?  it sounds promising. :)

Answer (score 9):

You might want to take some advice from Douglas Crockford (my emphasis):

> I have been writing JavaScript for 8 years now, and I have never once found need to use an uber function. ... **I now see my early attempts to support the classical model in JavaScript as a mistake**.

Douglas Crockford, [*Classical Inheritance in JavaScript*](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html),

Comment: I second this. JavaScript has its own idioms, and "porting" over classical inheritance is really nothing more than a crutch ... the language has its own reuse patterns and facilities that work just fine. (But, if I were going to adopt a classical inheritance pattern, Resig's is still a good one).

Comment: Hm, I think that a big problem is that these "own idioms" are too often either not very well understood or badly implemented. Giving a frame that is familiar (e.g. classical OO inheritance) makes the transition a lot easier (see Scala). Having a crutch is still better than crawling.

Comment: Daff - but once the error of implementing a class-based pattern is realised, there may be a lot of code to fix. Javascript inheritance isn't hard to learn, it just takes an open mind. Note that Resig's book slated for the fall of 2008 (September?) still hasn't been published and its title seems to be a more modest "Secrets of JavaScript". Perhaps Resig is also dobuting the usefulness of class based inheritance in javascript.

Comment: I don't really get that. You guys are saying that prototypal inheritance should be used instead? But then, how do you refer to the parent class? I think Crockford's comment at the end about "super" might have to do with something but I'm confused at this point.

Comment: You can worship Douglas Crockford if you want. I've been designing web applications for 12 years now and have found that emulating classical inheritance in JS is very simple and leads to cleaner more testable code. To each his own.

Comment: @JuanMendes—no worship, simply a quote from someone who is is on the TC39 committee that controls changes to ECMAScript and has significant experience with programming languages and development in general, not just the web. Interesting that the quote has been updated to 14 years (perhaps it's just a calculated value from the date the article was written).

Answer (score 2):

You may check out this extended version of John Resig's Class model:

https://github.com/riga/jclass

It's still build on prototypes but also provides private members using closures.